# How do I remove some of the apps in only mobile view?

Tags: 2013, mobile-view

I am working with a mobile SharePoint 2013 page and need some things to not appear on it. I only want certain apps to show on the mobile view of our website. There are some list and document files that I need to only appear on the computer browser but not on the mobile view of the same site.

Comment: Can you be more specific. What exactly are you trying to hide and on what pages?

Comment: Do you mean not to show the web part when you open the same pages in mobile? The mobile pages are same that you see on desktop?

Comment: The mobile site is too cluttered and I need to hide some document libraries and lists. But since it is the same webpage just formatted different I was wondering If there is a way to make only certain things appear on the mobile view of it.

Answer (score 0):

As you are looking to hide some of the content on mobile devices. You should use media queries in CSS.

Here is my approach which can be managed easily.

**Attach a class to the web parts which need to hide in mobiles**

I am using a jQuery to attach a class to my list view web parts. The following code I added using script editor web part to the pages where I need this change.

```
$("#web-part-d").addClass("hide-mobile");
```

**Add CSS**

The following CSS I added to the common.css which has been added to the master page.

```
@media (max-width:992px) { //this is for iPad
   .hide-mobile {
      display: none;
   }
} 

@media (max-width:767px) { //this is for mobile
   .hide-mobile {
      display: none;
   }
}
```

If you want this for only one page add the above CSS and JavaScript to the Script Editor web part.